# Can not set Session variables in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I know that my question is basic one yet i need some responses because i have tried many solutions on the net and i still get the some error.

I have a gridPanel in the first view. If i click a button in this view, the selected rows will be displayed in another view. I need to send information with these rows to the server so i can load some extra data in the action proper to the click button.
To perform that, i should use Session instead of TempData or ViewBag/ViewData because i don't know when the user will click the button. Please correct me if i'm mistaken.

My code is like that: In the client side with AJAX i call an action method to set the session variables:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ url: 'Examples/SetSelectedStations', params: { selectedStations: stationsStr} });
```

in the `SetSelectedStations` controller i realised that `Session["slectedStations"]` is always null and acts like have never been set. this is my controller action:

```
public ViewResult SetSelectedStations(string selectedStations)
        {
            Session["slectedStations"] = selectedStations;
            string ss = Session["slectedStations"] as string;
            // Here ss is null !!!!!!
            return View();
        }
```

Should i define Session["slectedStations"] in other place? Is there a special configuration in the web.confg file?

Please notice that the sessionState in my web.config is like that:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="PgSessionStateStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="PgSessionStateStoreProvider" type="NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.PgSessionStateStoreProvider" enableExpiredSessionAutoDeletion="true" expiredSessionAutoDeletionInterval="1800000" enableSessionExpireCallback="false" connectionStringName="AspSQLProvider" applicationName="WebSite1" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Comment: What is the point in setting session value in one line and retrieving it in the next one? If selectedStations parameter is not null then your code should work.

Comment: You can disable session storage in a web.config, so that could be your issue. More critically, Session is not really something that should be used with MVC. You really should be using a model to handle this data, and then the view can pass the data to whatever controller endpoint it calls next.

Comment: @dotnetom I want to say that even in the some controller selectedStations is null. looks like Session["slectedStations"] doesnt exist

Comment: Session can be turn on/off in the web.config. system.web -> sessionState. By default is on/InProc

Comment: @NickZimmerman the problem is i'm not sure that the next action will be to dispaly the selected rows in the new view: the user can perform other actions and after thet click the button so thats why i should use Session. How can i disable session storage in a web.config ?

Comment: what version of asp.net MVC you are using?

Comment: @CristianoDegiorgis i have added the sessionState configuration to my question. can you please tell how to configurate it

Comment: @kpadmanabhan it is MVC 3

Comment: As long as your provider has been properly written, should work. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx for more details about configuration